# How to fetch row in PDO?

Tags: php, pdo, fetch

Here is my code:

```
$qs_num = $this->dbh->query("SELECT COUNT(amount), COUNT(*) FROM qanda WHERE type = 0");
print_r($qs_num); die;
```

And here is the result:

```
//=> PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT COUNT(amount), COUNT(*) FROM qanda WHERE type = 0 )
```

How can I get the result of query above? That query should return 1 row contains tow columns.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the fetch method of the PDOStatement object like this:

```
$row = $qs_num->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php